# Switching heroku remote to another branch

Tags: git, heroku, git-remote

**Context:**

I had a nice clean way of managing my staging and production environment until I ruined the `develop` branch. This is what it looked like:

**staging environment:**

```
branch name: develop
heroku remote: forked/master
heroku app: staging-my-app
deploy: git push forked develop:master
```

**production environment:**

```
branch name: master
heroku remote: heroku/master
heroku app: my-app
deploy: git push heroku master
```

**Question**

I created a new branch `test_merge` which is a fixed version of the `develop` branch. Can I move my heroku remote `forked/master` from the `develop` to the `test_merge` branch? if so how? Doing this will allow me to deploy the code from `test_merge` to the staging app.

Comment: Why don't you merge `test_merge` into `develop`?

Comment: @ilopezluna I'd rather just abandon develop, its got too many problems.

Comment: And what about `git push forked test_merge:master` this way you will overwrite your remote branch. It's enough to fix your problem?

Comment: I guess that would work?